# Sockets not working for specific rooms

Tags: electrical, socket

Sockets are not working for couple of rooms and RCB circuit tripped off. I unplugged all equipment's but its still tripped off so unable to find faulty socket. Is there way to find faulty socket or do I need to call electrician?
There are few socket tester available in screwfix / toolstation but not sure whether it help as there are no power on sockets (due to RCB tripped). Please comment whether is there way to find faulty before electrician call.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a faulty RCB?

Comment: First make sure local regulations allow you to do more than just using switches and plugging stuff in outlets.   Second make sure RCD/RCB is working or not, usually by changing it.  After that it is a process of isolating sections of the circuit to see where the problem is.  Might be an outlet or a cable run.

Comment: Just to state the obvious: RCBs don't reset themselves when the fault is removed from the circuit. After you unplugged everything, you did turn the RCB back on, correct?  You're saying that it immediately tripped again?

Comment: Thanks Both. I think RCB is ok as rest of switches are working properly. I did on / off and all looks ok. My question is really whether Socket tester can help to identify fault socket even there is no power in it i.e. RCB tripped off. Is there any way to identify faulty socket (as I tried to isolate but didn;t work) or shall I call electrician.

Comment: @FreeMan - Yes. After unplugged everything, I tried to turn the RCB back on but it;s tripped again. It indicates problem is somewhere in socket circuit but not sure how to isolate it.

Comment: When trying to diagnose RCB problems, disconnecting sub-circuits is good... but disconnecting hot is not enough, you must also disconnect the partner neutral to that hot. Leakage can occur via the neutral as well. A common circuit breaker disconnects only the hot.

Comment: Thanks All. I will call electrician as RCB checking is something out side of my remit.

Answer (score 0):

(from Australia) Not a complete answer but as I don't have 50 points I can't comment, hope that this is ok. It could be that the RCB is the issue. This happened to me some months back. It would stay loaded until any appliance or load was switched on in any of the circuits it covered, Then it would trip. I got a sparky in. He replaced the RCB after testing the circuits with his megger.